# handle subpages inside facebook app (with one single tab)

Tags: facebook

My goal is that have a fb page app (only in one tab) and use it with linkable subpages inside it.

For example:
If I click on subpage link there would be a http or ajax request inside the iframe. Thats fine, i can do that.

BUT

in the solution I also want to implement these two features:

**1.:**

I want that page to be accessible directly from an url like:

http://facebook.com/pagename/app..blabla/subpage1
or
http://facebook.com/pagename/app..blabla&sk=535&subpage=1
or
http://facebook.com/pagename/app..blabla#subpage1

**2.:**

On subpage link click inside iframe I want the browser url to turn into something like mentioned in the 1. point. (even when using ajax - probably with a hash tag)

Is it possible?

Comment: Answering my question: it cant be done. Because if I want to rewrite the browser url I need to know that (read it into a js variable somehow). But I can only overwrite  the top frame url, and cannot read it. Strange but thats it.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the page tab tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ at the bottom of the page they describe how you can create the 'subpage' idea using the `app_data` parameter.  So your links will look like `http://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here`

For your second question, in the links on the page you would specify `target="_top"` in any links you have with the href being: `http://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=subpage1`.  This will cause the entire page tab to load through Facebook and you'll get the `signed_request` and your `app_data` parameters.

You probably don't want your ajax to load through facebook, because you'll get the Facebook page back instead of json or whatever you are trying to load.  Instead you'll just make ajax calls to your server and pass the parameters you need to, like `app_data` or whatever you want.

Comment: Ok, so there no way I can get the browser url (as shown in the address bar) from inside the app iframe. Right?
I mean I know that I cant in case of the parent is on a different domain and I cant access its source code. But I thought FB API built a support for it...

Comment: You can make a graph api call to `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID_FROM_SIGNED_REQUEST` and use the `link` value.